# Order of bean creation in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot app, and I am trying to verify the order in which certain beans are being created at startup. As far as I can tell via debugging, this is what is happening:

1. Beans defined in my `Configuration` classes are initialized.
2. Beans defined in auto configuration classes are initialized.
3. Classes annotated with `@Component` are initialized.

Steps 1 and 2 make sense to me, as this conforms to Spring Boot's documentation on [auto configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-bean-conditions).

What I don't understand is whether the `@Component` annotated classes are being deliberately initialized last, or if this is simply a coincidence. I don't want to rely on this as a "feature" when it is anything but.

Comment: They *generally* shouldn't be, since your component-scanned beans should override autoconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

I think in general, what beans are created when should not worry you. You will observe that a Bean which depends on other bean dependencies in its constructor will be created after its dependencies, but that's pretty much it.

Any patterns or behaviors you observer other than this should not be relied on in your logic. You may indeed find a pattern but the behavior could change in the future, though I don't know how likely that would be to occur.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, at least for my situation. The original question was born from an earlier issue in which it looked like certain beans couldn't be autowired because they hadn't yet been created. That problem seems to have gone away after a number of refactors, leading me to believe that, as this answer states, it was not the order of bean creation that was the problem, but something I was doing on my end.